# How to use or in roles discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, i have this code:

`role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == 'Member of IMP', lambda r: r.name == 'Blitzo', lambda r: r.name == 'Stolas', lambda r: r.name == 'Moxxie', lambda r: r.name == 'Millie', lambda r: r.name == 'Loona')`

And I'm trying to figure out how to make it mean : If user has "role" or "role" or "role"
I set up everything else all i need to know is how to use "or" in this situation

Answer (score 3):

You could use 1 single `lambda` and use the `in` operator on a `tuple` (or another iterable like a `list` or `set`).

```py
names = ("Member of IMP", "Blitzo", .....,)
role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name in names)
```

If you *really* want to use `or` then this is probably what you're looking for:

```py
role = discord.utils.find(lambda r: r.name == "name1" or r.name == "name2" or ....)
```

However, this becomes unmaintainable & unreadable very fast so I suggest the first.